# Android calculator app prevent adjacent operator input

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm trying to build an android calculator app. I'm trying to create a String like "351+193*123" using the buttons. In order to prevent syntax error, I have to preclude adjacent operators and decimal(+, -, *, /, .). But when i testing the app, double operators still can be input. Please take a look at the private Button.onClicklistener -> switch(v.getId()) -> case btnPlus, btnMinus, btnTimes, btnDivide, btnDot

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText edtShow;
    private Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9,
    btnPlus, btnMinus, btnTimes, btnDivide, btnEquals, btnDot, btnClear, btnBack;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        edtShow = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtShow);
        btn0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btnPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        btnTimes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTimes);
        btnDivide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);
        btnEquals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEquals);
        btnDot = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDot);
        btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        btn0.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn6.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn7.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn8.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btn9.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnTimes.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnDivide.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnEquals.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnDot.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(myListner);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(myListner);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener myListner = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick (View v)
        {
            String s = edtShow.getText().toString();
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.btn0:
                {
                    if(s.length() != 0)
                        {
                        edtShow.setText(s + 0);
                        }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn1:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 1);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn2:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 2);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn3:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 3);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn4:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 4);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn5:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 5);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn6:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 6);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn7:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 7);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn8:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 8);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btn9:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s + 9);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnPlus:
                {
                    if(s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "+" 
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "-"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "*"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "/"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != ".")
                    {
                        edtShow.setText(s + s.substring(s.length() - 1));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnMinus:
                {
                    if(s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "+" 
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "-"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "*"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "/"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != ".")
                    {
                        edtShow.setText(s + "-");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnTimes:
                {
                    if(s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "+" 
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "-"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "*"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "/"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != ".")
                    {
                        edtShow.setText(s + "*");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnDivide:
                {
                    if(s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "+" 
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "-"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "*"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "/"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != ".")
                    {
                        edtShow.setText(s + "/");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnDot:
                {
                    if(s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "+" 
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "-"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "*"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != "/"
                        && s.substring(s.length() - 1) != ".")
                    {
                        edtShow.setText(s + ".");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnClear:
                {
                    edtShow.setText("");
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnBack:
                {
                    edtShow.setText(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnEquals:
                {

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calculator, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing strings with != . This is not the Java way - Java has no operator overloading. You should use `string.equals`, like so:

```
if(!s.substring(0, s.length()-1).equals("+")) ...
```

That said, your code could use some cleaning up. All numeric buttons are the same and all operator buttons are the same - group them and have two event handlers - one for each type. You don't need a big switch statement for each one, just use the view's tag to hold the digit or operator.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use substring() method, you can use charAt() method, and you can compare with "==" operator. FOr eg;-

```
char last=s.charAt(s.length()-1);
if(last == '+'){
// its plus
}else{
//it's not plus
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

> .endsWith

like this

```
if(!s.endsWith("+")){
// input "+"
}
```